# Marvelous Designer Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I am hoping someone can help me with this problem. I've tried both Blender and Substance painter to try and replicate the materials I am getting in Marvelous Designer, but I cannot seem to reproduce a similar result.

Am I missing a node? Subsurface scattering of a similar blue maybe? I am completely stumped. My render in Blender ends up looking like plastic / leather vs the exact Nylon (winter jacket) look I am going for. I am using cycles with 3 area lights all set to white FYI.

I've attached a screen shot of both.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBTF4.jpg

EDIT: One quick fix I've found is cranking the metallic which reduced the light reflection but increases the material color reflection

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: is the second picture the one made with Blender? maybe try the Principled BSDF's Sheen, or even mix the Principled BSDF with a Glossy with a Fresnel as factor? you can share your file here: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots Yes it is. I actually think I've sorted it pretty well by doing exact what you suggested. Looks near identical now. I may explore a faint / fine density noise on the roughness or normal to get some tiny variations. Thank you for the reply